# linux command which outputs lines from a txt file which have numbers that are in a certain range

Tags: linux, command-line

say I have a txt file like this

```
hello:50:hello
hello:51:hello
hello:52:hello
hello:53:hello
hello:54:hello
```

what I want is a command that outputs something like this

```
hello:51:hello
hello:52:hello
hello:53:hello
```

so it outputs values between 51 and 53 inclusive

Comment: William Pursell answer was what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to give more specifics, but perhaps you are looking for:

```
awk '$2 < 54 && $2 > 50' FS=: input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below ...

```
$ cat  data.txt
hello:50:hello
hello:51:hello
hello:52:hello
hello:53:hello
hello:54:hello

$ awk -F: '$2>=a && $2<=b {print $0}' a=51 b=53 data.txt
hello:51:hello
hello:52:hello
hello:53:hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed`:

```
sed -n 2,4p input.txt
```